# How can I set GNU make variable to a valid name in windows

Tags: eclipse, makefile, cygwin, cocos2d-x

I am working on `cocos2dx` in windows using `eclipse`. I try to compile via `cygwin terminal` and i get the following error.

> ERROR: Your GNUMAKE variable is defined to an invalid name: E:\cygwin\bin
>   Please fix it to point to a valid make executable (e.g. /usr/bin/make)

I want to know how `gnu make` variable is set to a valid name. My environment variable is set as `e:\cygwin\bin\make`

Comment: same problem any response?

Answer (score 1):

`GNUMAKE` should be set to a path that is recognized by cygwin.  To find out, you can use `which` in a cygwin terminal:

```
$ which make
/cygdrive/e/cygwin/bin/make
```

You can also use `cygpath` to create the correct path:

```
$ cygpath 'e:\cygwin\bin\make'
/cygdrive/e/cygwin/bin/make
```